# nohup node service using cron job on CentOS 7

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, centos, cron

I want to run `nohup node service` using a cron job on CentOS 7. For this I created a file `/home/guest/start_indexjs` mentioned below:

```
#!/bin/bash

if pgrep -f "index.js" >/dev/null; then
echo "index.js is Running."
else
echo "index.js is Stopped."
nohup node /root/demo/index.js > /root/index-nohup.log &
fi
```

I login with `ssh root` and run following command:

```
cd /home/guest/
chown root start_indexjs
chgrp -R root start_indexjs
chmod +x start_indexjs
```

I want to run `/home/guest/start_indexjs` every minute. For this I added the following line into `/etc/crontab`:

```
*/1 * * * * root /home/guest/start_indexjs > /var/log/start_indexjs.log
```

I created `/var/log/start_indexjs.log` with the following permissions:

```
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root   root    179 Aug 12 12:31 start_indexjs
```

Then I restarted `crond` service using below command

```
systemctl restart crond.service
```

After all this, my cron job running but when `/home/guest/start_indexjs > /var/log/start_indexjs.log` run, in cron job, my `index.js` didn't run. There is no process running with `index.js` using following command:

```
ps -ef | grep index.js
```

Answer (score 1):

- In order to run script from `crond` you have to provide full path to all binaries, which are `pgrep` and `node` in your current case
- `nohup` is not necessary. `crond` runs scripts without allocating terminal.